# Export DataTables to Excel With Orange Background

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following snippet which allows for a red and green background to be shown on column F depending on the content of the cell

My question is, how would I go about doing it so I can have an orange background as well?

```
buttons: [{
  extend: 'excel',
  text: 'Save as Excel',
  customize: function(xlsx) {
    var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
    $('row c[r^="F"]', sheet).each(function() {
      if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Very aware'.toUpperCase() || $('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Reasonably aware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', '15');
      } else if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Slightly aware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', '10');
      } else if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Unaware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', '10');
      } else {

      }
    });
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the built-in styles of datatables only include options for gray `#D9D9D9`, red `#D99795`, green `#C6EfCE` and blue `#C6CFEF` backgrounds, you have to add the styles you need yourself.

Datatables stores the built-in styles in an object named `excelStrings` under the property `xl/styles.xml`. See: [Buttons/js/buttons.html5.js @ Line:582](https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/blob/master/js/buttons.html5.js#L582)

You can add custom styles by extending/customizing the excel-button like this:

```
{
  extend: 'excel',
  text: 'Save as Excel',
  customize: function(xlsx) {
    let sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

    let styles = xlsx.xl['styles.xml']; // Get current styles

    let last_fills_index = $('cellXfs fills', styles).length - 1;
    let last_xf_index = $('cellXfs xf', styles).length - 1;

    let fill_orange = '<fill><patternFill patternType="solid"><fgColor rgb="ffffb024" /><bgColor indexed="64" /></patternFill></fill>';
    let style_fill_orange = '<xf numFmtId="0" fontId="4" fillId="' + (last_fills_index + 1) + '" borderId="0" applyFont="1" applyFill="1" applyBorder="1"/>';

    styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].innerHTML += fill_orange; // childNodes[2] -> fills
    styles.childNodes[0].childNodes[5].innerHTML += style_fill_orange; // childNodes[5] -> cell xfs

    let sOrangeBackground = last_xf_index + 1;

    $('row c[r^="F"]', sheet).each(function() {
      if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Very aware'.toUpperCase() || $('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Reasonably aware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', '15');
      } else if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Slightly aware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', sOrangeBackground);
      } else if ($('is t', this).text().toUpperCase() == 'Unaware'.toUpperCase()) {
        $(this).attr('s', '10');
      }
    });
  }
}
```